# UiAutomator test suites (set of tests)

Tags: android, junit, functional-testing, android-uiautomator

I want to use `JUnit3` `TestSuite` feature with `UiAutomator for Android`.

I tried to create `TestSuite` class, `UiAutomatorTestCase` class with `public static Test suite()` method..

But none of this approaches worked.

`UiAutomator` supports only direct declaring of `Test` classes via `-c package.name.TestClass` arguements?

Answer (score 0):

Though you choose JUnit3 Tests, UIAutomator Testcase needs to be extended with  `com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase`

Source: [Link](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2014/02/08/uiautomator-in-eclipse/)

Yes you are right, Every class which extends `UiAutomatorTestCase` is a Testcase and can be accessed using `-c package.name.TestClass`

Comment: What do you want to say? Of course my test cases extends `UiAutomatorTestCase`. I am asking about `JUnit`'s test suites, I know about `-c` option, it is not a good solution

Comment: What are you talking about? `UiAutomatorTestCase` extends `TestCase` from JUnit3. JUnit is not eclipse/desctop framework, it's just a set of Java classes

Comment: What I meant is that JUNIT framework can be used to test your application only but using UIAutomator framework, we can test Android OS (Settings/WiFi/etc) as well along with your application.. I believe they both are different.. Please correct me if it doesn't make sense..

Comment: UiAutomator based on JUnit3, but does not support JUnit's TestSuite, that's all what I want to say to you

Comment: Check this tool [http://sourceforge.net/projects/uiautomator/](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uiautomator/). It has a provision to maintain a testsuite, not as in JUNIT though.